# Proper way to use repository-packages

Tags: fedora, rpm, dnf

My task is "find set of installed packages that belong to a repository". I try to do:

```
sudo dnf repository-packages REPO info installed
```

So I can determine if I need to disable it or not. But sometimes it shows "empty" even when I know I installed something from it. Take simple example:

```
sudo dnf repository-packages fedora-flash-plugin info installed
```

No packages listed. Because:

```
sudo dnf info flash-plugin
Last metadata expiration check: 0:15:04 ago on Tue Jul  5 17:22:04 2016.
Installed Packages
Name        : flash-plugin
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 11.2.202.626
Release     : 1.fc24
Size        : 18 M
Repo        : @System
From repo   : @commandline
```

It shows it as "Repo: @System" and "From repo: @commandline". Even though I know that Fedora does not package "flash-plugin". And it shows up in `sudo dnf history userinstalled | grep flash-plugin`.

It seems like a lot of packages, not just the ones from Fedora official repositories, are marked as "From repo: @commandline". What is the proper way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I know you're trying to use dnf for this but if yum is an option you could always do:

```
yum list installed |grep @REPO
```